# Delta distribution - integration by parts of its differentiation

Tags: mathematical-physics, calculus

Some delta distribution physicist calculus. Assume there is given

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \sum_i f(\mathbf{x}) \delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}_i) \ d^3x $$

with $f$ vanishing at infinity and $\delta^{(3)}=\delta_x\delta_y\delta_z$ and I want to approximate the integrand by "expanding" the delta distribution in the following way

$$ \sum_i \delta(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{a}_i) = \sum_i \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-\mathbf{a}_i \cdot \nabla)^n}{n!} \delta(\mathbf{x})$$

then I can change the order of integration and sum and I get

$$\sum_i \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \left[ \frac{(-\mathbf{a}_i \cdot \nabla)^n}{n!} \delta(\mathbf{x})\right] \ f(\mathbf{x}) \ d^3x$$

I now want to integrate by parts and my question is how exactly this is done. Is it formally correct or at least legitimate to proceed

$$(-\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla)^n \delta(\mathbf{x}) = (-\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla)(-\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla)...(-\mathbf{a}\cdot\nabla\delta(\mathbf{x}))$$

With other words, can I simply denote

$$\sum_i \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \underbrace{\left[ \frac{(-\mathbf{a}_i \cdot \nabla)^n}{n!} \delta(\mathbf{x})\right]}_{g'(x)} \ \underbrace{f(\mathbf{x})}_{h(x)} \ d^3x$$

and follow the rule $\int g'(x)\cdot h(x) \ dx = g(x) \cdot h(x) \big|_{-\infty}^{+\infty} - \int g(x) \cdot h'(x) \ dx$?

What will the result be and at which point do I use the delta distribution's definition

$$\int\delta(\mathbf{x})f(\mathbf{x}) \ d^3x=f(\mathbf{0})$$

and its property

$$\int \left[ \nabla \delta(\mathbf{x}) \right] \ f(\mathbf{x}) \ d^3x = -(\nabla f)(\mathbf{0}) ~?$$

Comment: Even if it was legitimate at all to Taylor-expand Dirac Peaks (it isn't; but perhaps you could handwave some conditions as to when the result might nevertheless be meaningful), then this would still be no use as an _approximation_, because you definitely would need to carry out the series to infinity. Any finite subseries has nothing to do with the Delta function.

Comment: @leftaroundabout truncating the taylor expansion for the delta function gives you the same answer for the integral as truncating the taylor expansion for $f$ around zero when trying to compute $f(a_i)$, so I would say taylor expanding the delta function is reasonable. On a side note, should this be migrated to math.se?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of expanding the $\delta $-function you can also rewrite the
integral as
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}d\mathbf{x}\sum_{i}f(\mathbf{x})\delta ^{3}(\mathbf{%
x-a}_{i})=\sum_{i}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}d\mathbf{x}f(\mathbf{x+a}_{i})\delta
^{3}(\mathbf{x}) \\
&=&\sum_{i}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}d\mathbf{x}f(\mathbf{x+a}_{i})\delta ^{3}(%
\mathbf{x})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}d\mathbf{x}\frac{1}{n!}%
\{(-\mathbf{a}_{i}\cdot \partial _{\mathbf{x}})^{n}f\}(\mathbf{x})\delta
^{3}(\mathbf{x}) \\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{n!}\{(-\mathbf{a}_{i}\cdot \partial _{%
\mathbf{x}})^{n}f\}(\mathbf{0})
\end{eqnarray*}
This presupposes infinite differentiability of the test function  $f$ and
convergence of the series but the result is the same. Actually derivatives
of $\delta $-distributions can be defined in this way.